# If a bidual space $X^{**}$ is isomorphic to a dual space $Y^*$, is there any relation between $(X, \rho|_X)^*$ and $Y$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

If a bidual space $X^{**}$ is isomorphically renormed to a dual space $Y^*$, 
 in other words  there exists a norm $\rho$ s.t.$(X^{**},\rho )=Y^*$, then is there any relation between $(X, \rho|_X)^*$ and $Y$?

Thank you in advance.